#  When does the rank of a module behave sub-multiplicatively under tensoring?

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, modules, dimension-theory, projective-modules

Let $\cal{E}$ be a finitely generated projective bimodule over a (noncommutative) algebra $A$. Moreover, let us assume that $\cal{E}$ is of finite rank $n$.  The tensor product 
$
\cal{E} \otimes_A \cal{E}
$
is again finitely generated, projective, and of finite rank. My question is when does it hold that
$$
\text{ rank}({\cal E} \otimes_A {\cal E}) \leq n^2 ~ ?
$$
To be more specific, I am looking for a set of sufficient (and hopefully natural) conditions for this to hold.

I will volunteer the condition of *locality* as a sufficient condition. Since in this case we have a well defined notion of minimal number of generators, which coincides with the rank, and so, the tensor product should (?) have a set of generators of size less than or equal to that of the square of the original generating set. I may be totally wrong here though!

[Edit] With regard to the definition of the rank of a projective module, I am using the one found [here](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Rank_of_a_module). The algebras I am interested in are sub-algebras of (noncommutative) Hopf algebras over the complex numbers, and so, the homomorphism $\phi$ can just be taken to be the counit $\epsilon$ of the Hopf algebra.

Comment: I think you must be missing some conditions if this is to make sense. For a general non-commutative algebra $A$, $\cal{E}\otimes_A\cal{E}$ only makes sense if $\cal{E}$ is both a left and right $A$-module structure.

Also, what do you mean by "rank"?

Comment: Yes, quite true, I am thinking here of bimodules, I will change it now.

Comment: What definition of rank are you thiking of?

Comment: P.S. For the definition of the rank of a projective module I am using the K-theoretic version found here
http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Rank_of_a_module

Comment: Even if $A$ admits a homomotphism to a field, the enveloping algebra need not, or am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by enveloping algebra here?


Comment: The ring over which bimodules are modules: $A^{op}\otimes A$.

Comment: Surely, you just take $\phi \otimes \phi$, which is well-defined because the field by definition is commutative.

Comment: Is that a ring homomorphism even if A is not commutative?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here but . . . for $a,b$ two elements of a generating set of $A$, we define $\phi^{op}(a) := \phi(a)$, and expand (anti-)multiplicatively, this is easily seen to be well-defined wrt the rels of $A^{op}$. Now we have $\phi^{op}(a.b) = \phi(b)\phi(a) = \phi(b)\phi(a) = \phi^{op}(a)\phi^{op}(b)$.

Comment: If $A$ is a Hopf algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, and you take $\cal{E}=A\otimes A$, then $\cal{E}$ is a finitely generated projective bimodule that has rank 1 by this definition, but $\cal{E}\otimes_A\cal{E}$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of $d=\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(A)$ copies of $\cal{E}$, and so will have rank $d$ (and won't even be finitely generated unless $A$ is finite-dimensional). Are you sure this is what you mean?